# mac dns look up misbehaving

Tags: macos, terminal, dns, lookup, ping

Got a new mac and now I'm trying to install/update some stuff. THe first issue I get is that http requests made from inside scripts/programs (such as git or ruby gem) doesn't work. I'll put an example below of the workaround I used because it illustrates the issue better than any explanation. Any help is appreciated!

```
Leonardos-MacBook-Air:~ leo$ git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
Cloning into '.rbenv'...
fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
# it can not find github.com

Leonardos-MacBook-Air:~ leo$ ping github.com
PING github.com (207.97.227.239): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 207.97.227.239: icmp_seq=0 ttl=50 time=104.279 ms
64 bytes from 207.97.227.239: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=105.658 ms
# it finds it in a ping, curl, or even a browser. this shows that it's not a network (proxy) issue


NOT SO ELEGANT SOLUTION
Leonardos-MacBook-Air:~ leo$ cat /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
207.97.227.239  github.com
# I added this last line in the /etc/hosts file

Leonardos-MacBook-Air:~ leo$ git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
Cloning into '.rbenv'...
remote: Counting objects: 1040, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (419/419), done.
remote: Total 1040 (delta 650), reused 959 (delta 593)
Receiving objects: 100% (1040/1040), 138.25 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (650/650), done.
# now it works
```

Answer (score 3):

My damn ISP's DNS server was the culprit here. After changing my router's DNS settings to [Google's public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).