# getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)

Tags: rubygems, themes, shopify, getaddrinfo

I'm developing a Shopify theme and I'm using https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme to update my files into Shopify.
Unfortunately, I can't get it to work... When I try to upload/update a file, I get an error like...

```
.....ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

I already saw this error while trying to install gems, apparently it's a "typical" problem with MacOS. I fixed the problem by changing my router DNS to Google's ones ([mac dns look up misbehaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766881/mac-dns-look-up-misbehaving)).

Unfortunately, the same problem appears while trying to use the gem (Shopify_theme) I installed. I'm quite new to this gem/rails world, so I don't really know how to fix this.

Any idea out there?

**EDIT:**
My bad, I actually found the solution. Sorry for this post, at least I'll explain how I fixed it.

I looked at the source files of this shopify_theme gem, and notice that it prepends "http://" before the shop url (defined with "theme configure api_key password store_url").
Because I first defined store_url WITH http://, this error shows up. If you get the same error, try to edit your config.yml file and remove "http://".

Comment: Seeing as you're on OSX I'd recommend the newer theme sync app: http://apps.shopify.com/desktop-theme-editor

Comment: Unfortunately, if I came to use the shopify_theme gem, it's because the new mac app you just mentioned is VERY buggy for now. It crashes anytime, and after adding sass files to my /assets/ folder, it just crashes everytime.

Comment: @user1821591 I was also experiencing frequent crashes with sass and the desktop theme app. So I moved the sass files to the parent folder  and changed the compile directory for the css. Now it's working smoothly.

Answer (score 9):

(Answering here so the thread appears answered.)

“I looked at the source files of this shopify_theme gem, and noticed that it prepends "http://" before the shop url (defined with "theme configure api_key password store_url").

Because I first defined store_url WITH http://, this error shows up. If you get the same error, try to edit your config.yml file and remove "http://".”

Comment: Yes I just figured this out the hard way too. I figured it was expected behavior for the stupid gem to prepend http:// to the store because I gave it the store without the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

xmlrpc will fail if a protocol is specified as part of the host.
Remove 'http://'