# Ruby on Rails - ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>=0) in any repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

I have a problem updating a turnkey redmine version from 1.4. to 2.6.0 on a virtual machine.
Before I can update it I need to update the rails version to 3.2.7 but when I use "gem install rails" I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I am using the guide I found on the turnkey website http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/general/20120722/guide-how-upgrade-redmine-latest-version-203-painlessly

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760379/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository. Seems that there the same problem

Comment: I tried the Proxy method and got the same problem after trying out 20 different proxys. The thing is I have to update ruby and rails in order to make it work, but since I am on a the turnkey environment I am not sure how to update both without having a connection to the rubygems.org website..